# Are there venomous plants?

Tags: botany, terminology, toxicology

There certainly are *poisonous* plants, but I was wondering, whether there are venomous specimen, too?

First, I thought the stinging nettle could be one such. After all, it's common knowledge it "applies a toxin upon touch". However, reading about [the mechanics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/34361/what-are-the-mechanistics-of-stinging-nettles) it seems that the injection is actually a much more passive procedure, which would render the plant poisonous, wouldn't it?

So what are some venomous plants?

Comment: By venomous, do you mean plants with parts, such as leaves or thorns that sting you with a toxic substance if you touch or get pricked by them?

Answer (score -3):

By definition, the word "venomous" can only technically be applied to animals.  The most "poisonous" plant would be the gympie gympie tree, but if you want something "venomous", you might be able to find something similar within some species of carnivorous plants.

Comment: That's interesting. I thought "venomous" simply meant the toxin is applied proactively, rather than passively by being ingested or such.

Comment: Please add references to your answer to support your claims.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, venom typically uses some form of injection, and doesn't need to be eaten to harm or kill you.  The gympie gympie tree uses silica tipped hairs to put a toxin into your flesh, much like how jellyfish do.  This tree is naturally found in Australia, because of course it is.  But it isn't only australia.  Stinging netals, definitely, and poison oak debatably are also venomous, since you don't have to eat them to take some form of chemical harm.